# Conditional tags returning different results for different areas on a page?

Tags: conditional-tags, pre-get-posts

I have a custom template. I want to output some JavaScript based on the type of page I am on. My current setup includes a static front page, with a template assigned it to it. This template is also a taxonomy archive page. I did this since I wanted the home page to be a taxonomy archive. When I hook into the `pre_get_posts`, I get different results in different areas of the page. Here is what I get:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'do_something');
function do_something($query) {
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Front: ' . $query->is_front_page .'<br>';
    echo 'Home: ' . $query->is_home .'<br>';
    echo 'Tax: ' . $query->is_tax .'<br>';
    echo 'Page: ' . $query->is_page .'<br>';
    echo 'Archive: ' . $query->is_archive('label') .'<br>';
    echo '</pre>';
}


//Homepage
Oustide the wrapper: Page - 1,
Sidebar: Home - 1
Content area: Tax - 1, Archive - 1

//On an archive page
Outside the wrapper: Tax - 1, Archive - 1,
Header: Archive - 1,
Sidebar: Home - 1,
Content: Tax - 1, Archive - 1
```

How can I make sure the conditionals return the appropriate page type? Do I need to change something in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I may have misinterpreted what you are asking here but you don't need to do this using pre_get_posts().

Instead you could either add this to your functions file:

```
function output_page_type() {
    global $post;
    $pagename = $post->post_name;
    return $pagename;
}
```

and then on the relevant page 
`echo output_page_type();` 
to get the page title.

Or you could use switch and the appropriate conditional tags i.e. is_page() is_home() is_tax() is_archive() etc. You can then output the correct page type that way. I like to do this in the header so its only needed once. For example:

```
    switch (n)
    {
    case is_home() :
      echo "Home";
      break;

    case is_page() :
      echo "Page";
      break;

    case is_category() : // Category
      echo "Category";
      break;

    case is_tag() : // Tags
      echo "Tag";
      break;

    case is_single() : // Single
      echo "Single";
      break;

    case $wp->query_vars['post_type'] : // Custom Post Type
      echo $wp->query_vars['post_type'];
      break;

    case is_tax() : // Custom Taxonomies
      echo "Tax";
      break;

    case is_archive() : // Standard Archive
      echo "Archive";
      break;

    default:
      echo "Some other randomness";
      break;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! My code actually does the same thing, I just have avoided the conditional checking! What I need to do is, accurately identify the type of page I am on and output some JavaScript.